# Vanishing rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am losing rows somehow and I am uncertain on how to move forward or even debug this one.  I read a record of about 500,000 rows into a pandas data frame.  There doesn't appear to be any nulls.  I normalize the data and viola, three rows have vanished.  As to which or how, I have no idea.  Here is what I am doing.

```
df = pd.read_sql(sql_string, con=db_connection)
df.isna().sum() # verify no null values
```

id               0
amount           0
current_count    0
hours            0
price            0

```
train_dataset = df.sample(frac=0.8,random_state=0)
train_stats = train_dataset.describe()
train_stats.pop("price")
train_stats = train_stats.transpose()
train_stats


               count        mean            std     min     25%     50%     75%     max
amount         539310.0     20639.065589    27150.823231    1.0     6200.00     12250.00    25997.00    1250000.00
current_count  539310.0     8.557446        5.155218    0.0     5.00    8.00    12.00   34.00
hours          539310.0     49.524289       64.611541   0.0     0.19    4.37    114.09  421.75

train_labels = train_dataset.pop('price') # split features from labels

#Normalize the data
def norm(x):
  return (x - train_stats['mean']) / train_stats['std']

normed_train_labels = norm(train_labels)

print('row count '+ str(normed_train_labels.shape[0]))
print('row count '+ str(train_labels.shape[0]))
```

**output**

row count 539313

row count 539310

So somehow I lost three rows?  non of my standard deviations are zero, so my norm function should not fail.  Any thoughts on what is going on or suggestions of tracking this down?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You are normalising with `train_stats` values rather than `train_labels` mean and sd.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please consider accepting my answer :)